# Copy Pywinauto module from one PC to another

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, pywinauto

I have pip installed the pywinauto module in my laptop. I want to install it on my work computer. But there is a proxy and I don´t know how to install pywinauto behind the proxy (I found on the internet that I should use --proxy http://user:pass@proxyAddress:proxyPort but I don´t have a username and password).

I thought maybe I could locate my Pywinauto file on my laptop and paste it on my fixed computer. I have already located it in my laptop (in \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto) but will it work to send it to my fixed computer and paste it on \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages?

Thank you very much

Comment: As a side note: Your companies IT department should tell you which proxy settings you need. You should not need to download work related software on your personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and copy latest pywinauto source code (now it is https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/refs/tags/0.6.8.zip), unpack it and run `python setup.py install` on your work PC. Though you need also to install dependencies the same way. They are all mentioned in [Manual Installation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#manual-installation).

BTW, `pip install` can work with local zip/tar.gz archive. I'd recommend to install `wheel` package first and then install `pywin32` from downloaded .whl file by pip.

P.S. In more complicated case it's possible to set up local PyPI index available in your work network without proxy. But I guess it's not so easy for you.